# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open. All the solutions out ther dont work for me

Tags: node.js, npm, enoent

I keep having this error, and i dont know what to do. This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const archivo = fs.readFileSync('C:\Users\marco\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\WebDeveloping\txt\test.txt');
console.log(archivo);
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:UsersmarcoOneDriveDesktopCodeWebDeveloping    xt      est.txt'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marco\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\WebDeveloping\js\index.js:57:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:UsersmarcoOneDriveDesktopCodeWebDeveloping\txt\test.txt'
}
```

All the files exist and thats the correct path for them

Answer (score 5):

You have to double your backslashes in order to end up with a single backslash in the string.  This is because the backslash is the escape character in Javascript strings so to actually get a backslash in the string, you need two of them in a row:

Change this:

```
const archivo = fs.readFileSync('C:\Users\marco\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\WebDeveloping\txt\test.txt');
```

to this:

```
const archivo = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\marco\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Code\\WebDeveloping\\txt\\test.txt');
```

You can see the issue in the error line:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:UsersmarcoOneDriveDesktopCodeWebDeveloping    xt      est.txt'
```

You will see that there are no backslashes there in that path and the extra whitespace is because `\t` is interpreted as a tab.

Comment: @marcomignacco - Did this work for you?