# Node on Ubuntu: ENOENT error, but file does exist, I am sure

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, smb

I have a JS script which attempts to copy CCTV files from one SMB location to another. All files are created in the same way are in essence the same. I am using **glob**
to get a list of all files.

90% of files copy just fine, however randomly some fail to copy. I am using

```
fs.readFileSync(filesArr[i]);
```

Which results in

[image]

Note I am showing the source file location and the destination at the top.

When I then use Files in Ubuntu I can see each file and open it!

I can not understand is why it works most of the time.

Comment: How are the files created, are they also created by your script?
Could you paste the text of the error log instead of a screenshot to ease searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error description from nodejs fs module openSync method ENOENT is quite expressive. A simple search and [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551322/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-all-the-solutions-out-ther-dont) lead me to the reason, that your filename string is not encoded in the right way, you should escape special characters and in your case space characters, I think.

Your filename from the error reads `Failed Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.150.2,share=qvrprorecording/File/Standard_Format/Ch001_Camera 001/Event002/2024-02-08/17/20240208-172457-172501.mp4'`and there is an empty space between `Camera` and `001`, which might lead to your error.

Please try to add slashes / encode / escape your filename strings and report back if this does the trick.

Edited: So I looked up [nodejs fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) documentation which says to see the POSIX [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) documentation for more details, where you can look up the `ENOENT` error and what it stands for.